# Unable to loop through properly in nested object/array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, foreach

I have an object(coming from MongoDB), that looks like this:

```
var test = [
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "childs": [
      {
        "name": "First child",
        "child_id": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Second child",
        "child_id": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "childs": [
      {
        "name": "First child",
        "child_id": 1
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I'm trying to loop through this and display each child as a separate item. This is how i'm doing it:

```
var response_items = [];

//Process relays as individual devices
test.forEach(function(device) {
    var response_item = {};
    response_item._id = device._id;

    //Process relays as individual devices
    device.childs.forEach(function(child) {
        response_item.name = child.name;
        response_item.child_id = child.child_id;
        //Return devices
        response_items.push(response_item);
    });
});

console.log(response_items);
```

But for some reason this is the result i got:

```
Array (3)
{_id: "1", name: "Second child", child_id: 2}
{_id: "1", name: "Second child", child_id: 2}
{_id: "2", name: "First child", child_id: 1}
```

The third item is correct, however the first and second is duplicated and i have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/om89y661/

Comment: Sure, you're mutating the same object inside the inner `forEach()`, so the next iteration overwrites the previous properties you set. You're then pushing that same object into the array. Instead, declare your `var response_item = {}` inside the inner `.forEach()`. JS never implicitly copies objects.

Comment: try putting the first two lines of code (var response_item={} ...) in the `device.childs.forEach()` or take a look at this fiddle (forked it) https://jsfiddle.net/5kyk7pbx/

Comment: I feel stupid... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var test = [
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "childs": [
      {
        "name": "First child",
        "child_id": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Second child",
        "child_id": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "childs": [
      {
        "name": "First child",
        "child_id": 1
      }
    ]
  }
];
    
var response_items = [];

//Process relays as individual devices
test.forEach(function(device) {

//Process relays as individual devices
device.childs.forEach(function(child) {
                var response_item = {};
 response_item._id = device._id;
  
 response_item.name = child.name;
 response_item.child_id = child.child_id;
 //Return devices
 response_items.push(response_item);
});

});

console.log(response_items);
```

Comment: as @squint said in the comment above. The inner loop is overwriting the object you created in the outer loop. This will prevent the closure by creating a new object in the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.reduce()` to flatten your array as below in a pure functional approach:

```js
var test = [
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "childs": [
      {
        "name": "First child",
        "child_id": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Second child",
        "child_id": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "childs": [
      {
        "name": "First child",
        "child_id": 1
      }
    ]
  }
];

var result = test.reduce(function (accumulator, current) {
  var mappedRes = current.childs.map(function (item) {
    item._id = current._id;
    return item;
  });
  return accumulator.concat(mappedRes);
}, []);

console.log(result);
```